# Visual Studio 2015 Setup Build and Simulate iOS in the Cloud

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am using ["Microsoft Build and Simulate iOS in the Cloud"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858446(v=vs.140).aspx) to establish a remote build on Macincloud.com.  I am getting the following errors when I try to build an IOS app

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line   Error        Not implemented
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))          0
>   Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line   Error        An error
>   occurred uploading to the build server https
>   //myserverinstance.macincloud.com:3000: Error: Hostname/IP doesn't
>   match certificate's altnames: "Host: myserverinstance.macincloud.com.
>   is not in the cert's altnames: DNS:MAC123.local, IP Address:FE80:etc,
>   IP
>   Address:123.12.123.123"   BlankCordovaApp3    C:\Users\ME\Documents\Visual
>   Studio 2015\Projects\BlankCordovaApp3\BlankCordovaApp3\MDAVSCLI   1

One item to mention is that I didn't have to install anything, vs-mda-remote  was already on my system in macincloud. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvego.png]

Any ideas how to get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing when using MacInCloud currently is you will need to use the machine's IP rather than host name since host name reported by the OS is not the same as the host name on the internet.

In the Terminal app, type:

```
ifconfig | grep "inet "
```

You'll then see something like this:

```
inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
inet 192.168.0.100 netmask oxffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.1
```

In this case you'd use 192.168.0.100 in place of the host name.

See here for additional details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn858446(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Thanks - it worked. Once you misstep, the fix takes a couple additional steps.  I added the macincloud.com build server instance - remote -  IP address in visual studio 2015 Ent RC via Tools->Options->Tools for Apache Cordova->Remote Agent Configuration in the Host Field.  When I did that, the security pin required resetting using vs-mda-remote generateClientCert at the remote system and reflected in the VS config.